# SQL Server order by a function value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

In the order by clause, can we specify a function? It works for inbuilt function like `ORDER BY NEWID()` since `NEWID()` is a function. But there I want to specify ordering by a custom function.

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[Func_RetentionPriorityStatus]
(
    @Priority varchar(3)
)
Returns varchar(50)
As
Begin

declare @ID int
set @ID = (select rop.ID from dbo.RetentionOutboundPriority rop where rop.Archived = 0);
declare @ColName varchar(50)



select 
  @ColName = Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')
from (select *
      from dbo.RetentionOutboundPriority
      where ID = @ID
      for xml path(''), type) as T(XMLCol)
  cross apply 
    T.XMLCol.nodes('*') as n(Col) 
where Col.value('.', 'varchar(10)') = @Priority

    RETURN @ColName

End
```

So the query is like this

```
select * from dbo.RetentionTele rt
inner join dbo.RetentionTeleNotInterested rtni
on rt.ID = rtni.RetentionTeleID
order by
```

And this is where the problem is, I have specified

```
order by [dbo].[Func_RetentionPriorityStatus](@currentPriority)

order by (select [dbo].[Func_RetentionPriorityStatus](@currentPriority))

order by + (select [dbo].[Func_RetentionPriorityStatus](@currentPriority))

order by convert(varchar, (select dbo.[Func_RetentionPriorityStatus](1)))

order by + convert(varchar, (select dbo.[Func_RetentionPriorityStatus](1)))
```

But none of them is working. Now I am not even sure if this can be done, and if it, can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you include the function in your select, give the column a name, then you can order by it.

Comment: None of those function calls are correlated to the outer query. So they will evaluate the same for all rows. And ordering by a value that is the same in all rows is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to pass the `ID` to you function as parameter. Then your function will return different values for each row and it would be used in `order by`.